# Qt operator != overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
I tried to overload the operator !=

    struct Antichoc 
    { 
        quint8 Chariot; 
        quint8 Frittage;

    bool operator!=(const Antichoc &a, const Antichoc &b) 
    { 
        return a.Chariot != b.Chariot || a.Frittage != b.Frittage; 
    }
    }
```

I get the error :

> bool Antichoc::operator!=(const Antichoc&, const Antichoc&) must take
>   exactly one argument

Why this error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non-static member functions take an implicit, hidden first parameter with a pointer to the same type. So your member operator actually has three parameters, where it should have two.

You could either make it a non-member operator:

```
struct Antichoc { .... };

bool operator!=(const Antichoc &a, const Antichoc &b) 
{ 
    return a.Chariot != b.Chariot || a.Frittage != b.Frittage; 
}
```

Or make it a member taking only one argument.

```
struct Antichoc 
{ 
    quint8 Chariot; 
    quint8 Frittage;

  bool operator!=(const Antichoc& rhs) const 
  { 
    return Chariot != rhs.Chariot || Frittage != rhs.Frittage; 
  }
};
```

The first version would allow for implicit conversions to `Antichoc`, which is not necessary in this particular example.

Usually it is good practice to implement `!=` in terms of `==`.

Note that in C++11 you can simplify all of these logical operators by using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple>

bool operator!=(const Antichoc &a, const Antichoc &b) 
{ 
    return std::tie(a.Chariot, a.Frittage) != std::tie(b.Chariot, b.Frittage); 
}
```